# Exporting Error 'Pattern 'VH' did not match any bands'?

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I am trying to process a Sentinel 1 image to add layover and shadow masking. However when I do that and try and export the image to google drive I get an error: `Error: Image.select: Pattern 'VH' did not match any bands.`

I am using Colab python to do this and my code for exporting is here:

```py
image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD/S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20160126T015925_20160126T015950_009659_00E14D_108C')
roi = {'long' : -120.318572, 'lat' : 39.310503000000004}
coords = ee.Geometry.Point(roi['long'], roi['lat'])
clip_area = coords.buffer(2000)
image_post = preprocess(image)
image_clipped = image.clip(clip_area)
image_clipped_post = preprocess(image_clipped)
image_post_clipped = image_post.clip(clip_area)
ID = 'testing_processing_v2'
folder = 'test'
imgGeom = image_clipped_post.geometry()
geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([roi['long'] - 0.05, roi['lat'] - 0.05, roi['long'] + 0.05, roi['lat'] + 0.05])
export_image(image_post_clipped.select('VV'), ID, folder, imgGeom)
```

The function I am using to preprocess the image is:

```py
 # Implementation by Andreas Vollrath (ESA), inspired by Johannes Reiche (Wageningen)
def preprocess(image):
  return mask_border(
      mask_overlay(
        terrain_correction(image)
      )  
  )

# Implementation by Andreas Vollrath (ESA), inspired by Johannes Reiche (Wageningen)
def mask_border(image):
    totalSlices = ee.Number(image.get('totalSlices'))
    sliceNumber = ee.Number(image.get('sliceNumber'))
    middleSlice = ee.Image(sliceNumber.gt(1).And(sliceNumber.lt(totalSlices)))
    mask = image.select(['VV', 'VH']).mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min()).floor()
    pixelsToMask = mask.Not()\
      .fastDistanceTransform(128, 'pixels').sqrt()
    metersToMask = pixelsToMask\
      .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea().sqrt())\
      .rename('metersToMask')
    notBorder = metersToMask.gte(500).And(pixelsToMask.gt(2))
    angle = image.select('angle')
    return image\
        .updateMask(
            angle.gt(31).And(angle.lt(45))
            .And(middleSlice.Or(notBorder))
        )

# Implementation by Andreas Vollrath (ESA), inspired by Johannes Reiche (Wageningen)
def mask_overlay(image):
  return image.updateMask(
      image.select('shadow').And(image.select('layover'))
  )

 # Implementation by Andreas Vollrath (ESA), inspired by Johannes Reiche (Wageningen)
def terrain_correction(image):
  imgGeom = image.geometry()
  srtm = ee.Image('JAXA/ALOS/AW3D30_V1_1').clip(imgGeom) # 30m srtm 
  sigma0Pow = ee.Image.constant(10).pow(image.divide(10.0))

  # Article ( numbers relate to chapters)
  # 2.1.1 Radar geometry 
  theta_i = image.select('angle')
  phi_i = ee.Terrain.aspect(theta_i)\
                           .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), theta_i.get('system:footprint'), 1000)\
                           .get('aspect')

  # 2.1.2 Terrain geometry
  alpha_s = ee.Terrain.slope(srtm).select('slope')
  phi_s = ee.Terrain.aspect(srtm).select('aspect')

  # 2.1.3 Model geometry
  # reduce to 3 angle
  phi_r = ee.Image.constant(phi_i).subtract(phi_s)

  # convert all to radians
  phi_rRad = phi_r.multiply(math.pi/180)
  alpha_sRad = alpha_s.multiply(math.pi/180)
  theta_iRad = theta_i.multiply(math.pi/180)
  ninetyRad = ee.Image.constant(90).multiply(math.pi/180)

  # slope steepness in range (eq. 2)
  alpha_r = (alpha_sRad.tan().multiply(phi_rRad.cos())).atan()

  # slope steepness in azimuth (eq 3)
  alpha_az = (alpha_sRad.tan().multiply(phi_rRad.sin())).atan()

  #local incidence angle (eq. 4)
  theta_lia = (alpha_az.cos().multiply((theta_iRad.subtract(alpha_r)).cos())).acos()
  theta_liaDeg = theta_lia.multiply(180/math.pi)
  # 2.2 
  # Gamma_nought_flat
  gamma0 = sigma0Pow.divide(theta_iRad.cos())
  gamma0dB = ee.Image.constant(10).multiply(gamma0.log10())
  ratio_1 = gamma0dB.select('VV').subtract(gamma0dB.select('VH'))

  # Volumetric Model
  nominator = (ninetyRad.subtract(theta_iRad).add(alpha_r)).tan()
  denominator = (ninetyRad.subtract(theta_iRad)).tan()
  volModel = (nominator.divide(denominator)).abs()

  # apply model
  gamma0_Volume = gamma0.divide(volModel)
  gamma0_VolumeDB = ee.Image.constant(10).multiply(gamma0_Volume.log10())

  # we add a layover/shadow maskto the original implmentation
  # layover, where slope > radar viewing angle 
  alpha_rDeg = alpha_r.multiply(180/math.pi)
  layover = alpha_rDeg.lt(theta_i);

  # shadow where LIA > 90
  shadow = theta_liaDeg.lt(85);

  # calculate the ratio for RGB vis
  ratio = gamma0_VolumeDB.select('VV').subtract(gamma0_VolumeDB.select('VH'))

  output = gamma0_VolumeDB.addBands(ratio).addBands(alpha_r).addBands(phi_s).addBands(theta_iRad)\
                              .addBands(layover).addBands(shadow).addBands(gamma0dB).addBands(ratio_1)

  return image.addBands(
    output.select(['VV', 'VH', 'slope_1', 'slope_2'], ['VV', 'VH', 'layover', 'shadow']), 
    None, 
    False
  )
```

The things I have tried so far:

1. check the bands on image are only 'VV' and 'angle'
2. remove all references to 'VH' in preprocessing -> I get error - `Error: Image.constant: Parameter 'value' is required.` I would prefer not to remove the 'VH' as well since I may want to use this function with images that have 'VH' as well later.
3. change order of clipping and processing -> didn't help
4. When I remove the preprocessing step then this exports fine so I think it is in that code I am getting this error

I can include the code with all 'VH's removed but I was still getting that error.

I don't know if it matters but here is the code to the export function as well.

```py
def export_image(image, ID, folder, geometry, scale = 10):
  image = image.toFloat()
  task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(**{
  'image': image,
  'description': ID,
  'folder': folder,
  'scale': scale,
  'region': geometry
  })
  task.start()
  while task.active():
    print('Polling for task (id: {}).'.format(task.id))
    print('Status: ',task.status().get('state'))
    time.sleep(3)
  else:
    if task.status().get('state') == 'FAILED':
      print('FAILED')
    print("Done: " + ID)
  return()
```

This might be too much to get help on I have just been stuck for quite a few days and figured I would at least try here as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with the code:

- You're invoking `export_image()` with the wrong argument order.
- Like you
  pointed out, your image doesn't contain a `VH` band. You have to remove all references to it. Instead of doing that, I typically filter out images that doesn't contain both `VV` and `VH`.
- There is problems with your geometry. I didn't try to figure out what, because you've clipped your image, so you actually don't need to provide the geometry at all.

This exports for me:

```
import ee
import math
import time
ee.Initialize()

def preprocess(image):
  return mask_border(
      mask_overlay(
        terrain_correction(image)
      )  
  )

def mask_border(image):
    totalSlices = ee.Number(image.get('totalSlices'))
    sliceNumber = ee.Number(image.get('sliceNumber'))
    middleSlice = ee.Image(sliceNumber.gt(1).And(sliceNumber.lt(totalSlices)))
    mask = image.select(['VV']).mask().reduce(ee.Reducer.min()).floor()
    pixelsToMask = mask.Not()\
      .fastDistanceTransform(128, 'pixels').sqrt()
    metersToMask = pixelsToMask\
      .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea().sqrt())\
      .rename('metersToMask')
    notBorder = metersToMask.gte(500).And(pixelsToMask.gt(2))
    angle = image.select('angle')
    return image\
        .updateMask(
            angle.gt(31).And(angle.lt(45))
            .And(middleSlice.Or(notBorder))
        )

def mask_overlay(image):
  return image.updateMask(
      image.select('shadow').And(image.select('layover'))
  )

 # Implementation by Andreas Vollrath (ESA), inspired by Johannes Reiche (Wageningen)
def terrain_correction(image):
  imgGeom = image.geometry()
  srtm = ee.Image('JAXA/ALOS/AW3D30_V1_1').clip(imgGeom) # 30m srtm 
  sigma0Pow = ee.Image.constant(10).pow(image.divide(10.0))

  # Article ( numbers relate to chapters)
  # 2.1.1 Radar geometry 
  theta_i = image.select('angle')
  phi_i = ee.Terrain.aspect(theta_i)\
                           .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), theta_i.get('system:footprint'), 1000)\
                           .get('aspect')

  # 2.1.2 Terrain geometry
  alpha_s = ee.Terrain.slope(srtm).select('slope')
  phi_s = ee.Terrain.aspect(srtm).select('aspect')

  # 2.1.3 Model geometry
  # reduce to 3 angle
  phi_r = ee.Image.constant(phi_i).subtract(phi_s)

  # convert all to radians
  phi_rRad = phi_r.multiply(math.pi/180)
  alpha_sRad = alpha_s.multiply(math.pi/180)
  theta_iRad = theta_i.multiply(math.pi/180)
  ninetyRad = ee.Image.constant(90).multiply(math.pi/180)

  # slope steepness in range (eq. 2)
  alpha_r = (alpha_sRad.tan().multiply(phi_rRad.cos())).atan()

  # slope steepness in azimuth (eq 3)
  alpha_az = (alpha_sRad.tan().multiply(phi_rRad.sin())).atan()

  #local incidence angle (eq. 4)
  theta_lia = (alpha_az.cos().multiply((theta_iRad.subtract(alpha_r)).cos())).acos()
  theta_liaDeg = theta_lia.multiply(180/math.pi)
  # 2.2 
  # Gamma_nought_flat
  gamma0 = sigma0Pow.divide(theta_iRad.cos())
  gamma0dB = ee.Image.constant(10).multiply(gamma0.log10())
  ratio_1 = gamma0dB.select('VV')

  # Volumetric Model
  nominator = (ninetyRad.subtract(theta_iRad).add(alpha_r)).tan()
  denominator = (ninetyRad.subtract(theta_iRad)).tan()
  volModel = (nominator.divide(denominator)).abs()

  # apply model
  gamma0_Volume = gamma0.divide(volModel)
  gamma0_VolumeDB = ee.Image.constant(10).multiply(gamma0_Volume.log10())

  # we add a layover/shadow maskto the original implmentation
  # layover, where slope > radar viewing angle 
  alpha_rDeg = alpha_r.multiply(180/math.pi)
  layover = alpha_rDeg.lt(theta_i);

  # shadow where LIA > 90
  shadow = theta_liaDeg.lt(85);

  # calculate the ratio for RGB vis
  ratio = gamma0_VolumeDB.select('VV')

  output = gamma0_VolumeDB.addBands(ratio).addBands(alpha_r).addBands(phi_s).addBands(theta_iRad)\
                              .addBands(layover).addBands(shadow).addBands(gamma0dB).addBands(ratio_1)

  return image.addBands(
    output.select(['VV', 'slope_1', 'slope_2'], ['VV', 'layover', 'shadow']), 
    None, 
    False
  )

def export_image(image, ID, folder, scale = 10):
  image = image.toFloat()
  task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(**{
  'image': image,
  'description': ID,
  'folder': folder,
  'scale': scale
#   'region': geometry
  })
  task.start()
  while task.active():
    print('Polling for task (id: {}).'.format(task.id))
    print('Status: ',task.status().get('state'))
    time.sleep(3)
  else:
    if task.status().get('state') == 'FAILED':
      print('FAILED')
    print("Done: " + ID)
  return()


image = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD/S1A_IW_GRDH_1SSV_20160126T015925_20160126T015950_009659_00E14D_108C')
roi = {'long' : -120.318572, 'lat' : 39.310503000000004}
coords = ee.Geometry.Point(roi['long'], roi['lat'])
clip_area = coords.buffer(2000)
image_post = preprocess(image)
image_clipped = image.clip(clip_area)
image_clipped_post = preprocess(image_clipped)
image_post_clipped = image_post.clip(clip_area)
ID = 'testing_processing_v2'
folder = 'test'
geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([roi['long'] - 0.05, roi['lat'] - 0.05, roi['long'] + 0.05, roi['lat'] + 0.05])
export_image(image=image_post_clipped.select('VV'), ID=ID, folder=folder)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I didn't realize that I didn't need to provide a geometry with clipped image. I have relatively few images to work with so I think I will just create an alternative set of functions to preprocess with ['VH'] included as well. Thanks again!